# Display message to authenticated users

Tags: forms

I have a Drupal site and my problem is that it doesn't display error messages when authenticated users are filling in, but they display with the administrator users.

An example of the messages I am referring to is "image size too exceed […]."

How can I make the error messages appear for every users?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Disable Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/disable_messages) Module. and set permission for user roles you want.

> Gives a site owner options to disable specific messages shown to end
>   users. The core drupal message system as offered by drupal_set_message
>   is an excellent way for modules to send out messages to the end users.
>   However not all drupal site owners are keen to show all the messages
>   sent out by drupal core and all modules to their users. This module
>   gives site administrators a reasonably powerful way to filter out
>   messages shown to the end users.

Comment: Thanks zhilevan, I have installed the module and enabled the options but the error message is still not showing

Comment: @jonazz you're welcome,  is the theme used by both users is equal?

Comment: no its not equal, the one for authenticated users is limited

Comment: @jonazz try use admin theme for authentication  user, (it is just for debug purpose) and tell me about the result